# eliminate inline <script> in file generated by doxygen

Tags: doxygen

A proposed change to the Content Security Policy (CSP) of our web server to disallow inline script
is causing a problem with the documentation generated by doxygen. Specifically, the problem occurs
in the generated index.html file, and the following lines:

```
<!-- Generated by Doxygen 1.8.15 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="menudata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* @license magnet:?xt=urn:btih:cf05388f2679ee054f2beb29a391d25f4e673ac3&amp;dn=gpl-2.0.txt GPL-v2 */
$(function() {
  initMenu('',false,false,'search.php','Search');
})
/* @license-end */</script>
```

If the `initMenu()` code is put into a separate file that is just included like other JavaScript files, everything
works just fine. Is there a doxygen option to put all JavaScript into files rather that inline? We can
post process the generated file to do this, but may not know when the "pattern" of this code may
change due to updates in doxygen itself. And we may not know if using additional doxygen features will result in other inline JavaScript.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you

Fritz Sieker

Answer (score 0):

First off Content Security Policy is useful but far from being an absolute authority. There are other completely useless headers such as those that block referrers based on "privacy".

Secondly there is no such thing as "text/javascript", perhaps they meant `application/javascript`?

If you're using good (though very non-common practices) you don't have any `script` elements in the `body` element (use `defer="true"` on `script` elements in the `head`). By doing that you'll better understand the structure of JavaScript and that in turn will help you become more proficient/capable/help more people/make more money/etc.

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('script')` to find all the `script` elements in the `body` element that don't belong there.

If you *do* have `script` elements in the `body` element beforehand and moving them to the `head` element is not feasible right now you're likely going to have to work with `inherent logic`, in short those `script` elements will always be inserted in to the DOM in a specific and reasonably easily reproducible area of your code (like as the very last elements). In such a case you can find them via the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].lastChild
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].lastChild.previousSibling
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].lastChild.previousSibling.previousSibling
```

Keep in mind that pressing *Enter* in your code to make it more readable will insert a `textNode` so you may want to append `nodeName` to those instances and look for "script":

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].lastChild.nodeName);
```

There is the DOM [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Treewalker) that might help you out here, subjective to the end result in your DOM. I don't know offhand if you can transverse all the elements in reverse (probably).

Once you know *what* you want to delete instead of making everything convoluted just send that object (or `id`) to the following:

```
function element_del(id)
{
 if (typeof id=='string' && id_(id) && id_(id).parentNode.removeChild)
 {
  id_(id).parentNode.removeChild(id_(id));
 }
 else if (typeof id=='object' && typeof id.parentNode=='object') {id.parentNode.removeChild(id);}
}

//Example:
element_del(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].lastChild);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Looking at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp I see that here the following is used: `<script type="text/javascript">` this is a bit strange in conjunction with your statement 'there is no such thing as "text/javascript"'.

Comment: @albert W3 Schools isn't an authorative site and what you pointed out is *exactly* the kind of example why professionals avoid using that site for reference.

Comment: Can you give a reference to an authoritative site? (Also strange that, the none authoritative site, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script also gives the possibility of `text/javascript` and I'm not sure whether https://html.spec.whatwg.org/  is authoritative (4.12.1 The script element) but here I also see `text/javascript` (and also https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/ links refers to this site).

Comment: @albert I'll make sure that after I fire the people copy-and-pasting in to standards that those issues are corrected.

Comment: So are you now saying that it is possible? or otherwise provide a reference to the standard from which it is clear that `text/javascript` is not allowed.

Comment: @albert No, I'm saying there are a lot of incompetent people. I'm also saying I've seen standards set years ago such as HTTPS suddenly change to exclude referrers because of political corruption. But hey, tediously drawn out conversations are *definitely* what comments were intended for on Stack.

Comment: That is why I asked a number of times already for: " provide a reference to the standard from which it is clear that text/javascript is not allowed".